# Loading CSS in lightning component as static resource?

Tags: css, salesforce, apex

I got the Salesforce Design System pilot from this morning's Webinar. I uploaded the package (as 'sds.zip') as a static resource. I'm calling the CSS (immediately after '' in the .cmp file) with:

```
<link href='/resource/sds/index.scss' rel="stylesheet"/>
```

However when I attempt to save I get the error:

```
Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named markup://use found : [markup://c:contactList]: Source
```

​I think the 'use' error is a refrence to this code block, which is later in the .cmp file:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--large icon-standard-user">
    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user" />
</svg>
```

I assume I'm importing the CSS incorrectly, what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the CSS correctly. That's the way to do it from inside a Lightning Component. From inside a Visualforce page you do `<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.sds, '/resource/sds/index.css')}" />`.

The problem is not the CSS import but VF not understanding the `use` and `svg` tags inside the component. For Visualforce to properly parse the tags you need to declare the namespace by adding the line `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`, with its matching closing tag at the end. This works fine if you just put it in VF, and you are using the `svg` tag in VF.

However, if you are putting the `svg` tag inside a Lightning Component, you need to create a separate svg component for it, as described in this [tutorial](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/).